# Find the highest distance in vector

Tags: algorithm

I have an array of positive integers. The problem is to find the highest 
distance in vector. The Distance is calculated as A[p] + A[q] + (q - p), where A is a vector p, q are indexes and p<=q. The complexity of the solution must be O(n). I'm able to solve this problem with a O(n^2) solution, but I can't find a O(n) algorithm for this problem.

Someone could help me? Thanks in advance. Which language is used to find the solution doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the objective as (A[p] - p) + (A[q] + q). The first term is a function only of p, and the second term is a function only of q. Thus they can be optimized separately subject to p ≤ q. As we increase q from 0 to n-1, the best choice of p can be computed from the previous best and A[q] - q.

```
def highest_distance(A):
    highest = float('-inf')
    max_Ap_minus_p = float('-inf')
    for q in range(len(A)):
        max_Ap_minus_p = max(max_Ap_minus_p, A[q] - q)
        highest = max(highest, max_Ap_minus_p + (A[q] + q))
    return highest
```

Comment: Where I had my head? :D Thank you so much